# splitting the URL using jQuery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

URL:

```
http://testwebsite.com/page1.aspx#page/1
```

I want to split the URL upto aspx using jQuery or Javascript, meant I want to split the URL so that it should be:

```
 http://testwebsite.com/page1.aspx
```

I have tried this code;

```
var url=document.URL;
var arr=url.split('#');
var myoutput=arr[0];
```

Is it the right way to split? Is there any other way which is reliable and better?

Comment: location.host + location.pathname.split('#')[1];

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could just use `location.host + location.pathname` to generate the specific page path instead of trying to split down a string to contain only what you want it to.

Comment: +1 - but `location.origin` might be better than `location.host`, depending on usage.

Comment: location.origin returning http:// is that it is intended for? what is difference between host and origin?

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
var url=window.location.href;
var arr=url.split('#')[0];
```

[**Fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/U59vA/)

Answer (score 0):

If your intended goal is to grab the URL up to the point of the .aspx extension, I would suggest splitting the URL at the extension and then appending it to the split. This would account for other symbols that could possibly precede the extension:

```
var url = document.URL,
    arr = url.split('.aspx'),
    myOutput = arr[0] + '.aspx';
```