# How to find url parameter # with value in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to find url parameter # with value in javascript.

my url is like:

> http://rohitazad.com/wealth/tax/how-to-file-your-income-tax-return/newslist/34343443.cms?intenttarget=no&utm_source=newsletter&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=ETwealth&type=wealth#sid53239948&ncode=23432kjk#%kjimwer

i want to find this value `#sid53239948`

I find this [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

but how to find this value in url?

Comment: This is a hash. No jQuery needed, just use `window.location.hash`

Comment: yes but multiple has tag in my url i want to find only #sid value

Comment: Hmmmm. You're going to need to find a rule, and then use a regex.

Comment: Something like `/(#sid[\w\d]+)/g`

Comment: follow this to get url then split it
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20190054/splitting-the-url-using-jquery-or-javascript

Comment: @RohitAzad just copy and paste my code in browser's console  and see (where you have url parameters with value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:
This will filter the sid into the `sid`-variable wherever you put your hash.

```
var url_arr = window.location.hash.split('&'),
    sid = '';

url_arr.filter(function(a, b) {
    var tmp_arr = a.split('#')
    for (var i in tmp_arr)
        if (tmp_arr[i].substring(0, 3) == 'sid')
            sid = tmp_arr[i].substring(3, tmp_arr[i].length)
});

console.log(sid) // Will output '53239948'
```

Old answer:

```
var hash_array = window.location.hash.split('#');
hash_array.splice(0, 1);
console.log(hash_array);
```

Comment: but i have multiple # in my url and i want to only #sid

Comment: there might be more than one hash entries

Answer (score 0):

use this plugin that help you to find exact information

https://github.com/allmarkedup/purl

Comment: sorry i m using only javascript no plugin

Answer (score 0):

Try this way,

```
var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
            // console.log(window.location.href);
            // console.log(hashes);
            for(var index = 0; index < hashes.length; index++)
            {
                var  hash = hashes[index].split('=');

                var value=hash[1];
                console.log(value);

            }
```

Comment: not correct show to this "wealth#sid53239948"  but i want to find with #sid and than completed value #sid53239948

Comment: @RohitAzad  "wealth#sid53239948" is not  a utm parameter its value value  of parameter "type"

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp

Search a string for "welcome":

```
var str = "Hello world, welcome to the universe.";
var n = str.indexOf("welcome");
```

The result of n will be:13. Maybe this helps you. In the posted link in your question you see how you get the url. But be careful: indexOf only returns the 1st occurence.

Answer (score 0):

The post you have referenced is looking for a URL parameter in a string. These are indicated by:

```
?{param_name}={param_value}
```

What you are looking for is the anchor part of the URL or the hash.

There is a simple Javascript function for this:

```
window.location.hash
```

Will return:

```
#sid53239948
```

See reference:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_hash.asp

However, given a URL that has multiple hashes (like you one you provided), you will need to then parse the output of this function to get the multiple values. For that you will need to split the output:

```
var hashValue = window.location.hash.substr(1);
var hashParts = hashValue.split("#");
```

This will return:

```
['sid53239948', '%kjimwer']
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have hash values in query params, `window.location.hash` will not work for you. You can try to create an object of query parameters and then loop over them and if `#` exists, you can push in a array.

#### Sample

```js
function getQStoObject(queryString) {
  var o = {};
  queryString.substring(1).split("&").map(function(str) {
    var _tmp = str.split("=");
    if (_tmp[1]) {
      o[_tmp[0]] = _tmp[1];
    }
  });
  return o
}

var url = "http://rohitazad.com/wealth/tax/how-to-file-your-income-tax-return/newslist/34343443.cms?intenttarget=no&utm_source=newsletter&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=ETwealth&type=wealth#sid53239948&ncode=23432kjk#%kjimwer";

// window.location.search would look like this
var search = "?intenttarget=no&utm_source=newsletter&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=ETwealth&type=wealth#sid53239948&ncode=23432kjk#%kjimwer";

var result = getQStoObject(search);
console.log(result)

var hashValues = [];
for(var k in result){
  if(result[k].indexOf("#")>-1){
    hashValues.push(result[k].split('#')[1]);
  }
}

console.log(hashValues)
```

`

Answer (score 0):

This solution will return you both values following `#`.

```js
var url = 'http://rohitazad.com/wealth/tax/how-to-file-your-income-tax-return/newslist/34343443.cms?intenttarget=no&utm_source=newsletter&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=ETwealth&type=wealth#sid53239948&ncode=23432kjk#%kjimwer';
var obj = url.split('?')[1].split('&');
for(var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
  
  var sol = obj[i].split('#');
  if(sol[1]) {console.log(sol[1]);}
}
```

Comment: Instead of `url.split(?)`, you can use `window.location.search` and create a mimic variable in your code